# Showing existence of positive weak solution of a PDE by CoV

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, sobolev-spaces, elliptic-pde, calculus-of-variations

Given the following PDE
$$
\begin{cases}
-\Delta u+\alpha=u^q &x\in\Omega\\
u=0 &x\in\partial\Omega
\end{cases}
$$
where $\Omega\subset\mathbb R^3$ is open bounded with smooth boundary, $1<q<5$, and $\alpha>0$ is a constant.

I am trying to show this PDE has at least a positive weak solution. Here is what I tried so far:

Define the energy functional
$$ E[u]=\frac{1}{2}\int_\Omega |\nabla u|^2dx +\alpha \int_\Omega |u|\,dx $$
and the admissible set
$$ \mathcal A:=\{u\in H_0^1(\Omega),\,\|u\|_{L^{q+1}(\Omega)}=1 \}$$
Hence by directly method we have a minimizer $u$ over admissible set $\mathcal A$. Also, notice that $E[u]=E[|u|]$ and hence we could assume the minimizer $u$ is non-negative. Therefore, by Lagrange Multiplier we have, for some $k\in\mathbb R$,
$$ \int_\Omega\nabla u\nabla v\,dx+\alpha\int_\Omega \frac{u}{u}v\,dx=k\int_\Omega u^qv\,dx$$
for all $v\in H_0^1(\Omega)$.

Now the last step is to show that $u\neq 0$ a.e. and hence the term 
$$  \alpha\int_\Omega \frac{u}{u}v\,dx\tag 1$$
is well-judged. However, I got stuck here... Any help is really welcome!

PS: I have another way to obtain a positive (classical) solution of this PDE but it takes too many pages but I don't want my paper to contain too many tactical details about this part...

Comment: Why is this the last step? You would get that $-\Delta u+\alpha=ku^q$ weakly, which doesn't seem to be exactly what you want.

Comment: @JLA the problem is that if $u=0$ on a positive set, then term $(1)$ does not make sense right?

Comment: @JLA weak solution is enough, since we could use boot-strap to get classical solution

Comment: Sure, but I thought you wanted a solution of $-\Delta u+\alpha=u^q\,,$ not $-\Delta u+\alpha=ku^q$ for some $k\,.$

Comment: @JLA Oh I see. Yes, but that $k$ does not matter for me now. All I need is a weak solution.

Comment: maybe try replacing $$\int_\Omega |u| dx$$ with $\int_\Omega (u)_+ dx$...  maybe ???

Comment: actually omit above idea.  I guess with this approach minimizer would always be nonpositive...